# What are default units for coordinates in Create Fishnet tool of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, vector-grid, units

This has been a reoccurring issue for me using ArcGIS Pro - when creating a fishnet and specifying the extent from an existing layer and subsequently trying to set the cell size, I am getting a mysterious unit.

I cannot specify the unit in the parameters or the environment and it is not linked to the CRS I am using. Comparing with different measurements it seems to be in meters, which doesn't make much sense given that my set CRS is WGS84. This happens for every dataset I tried so far.

Is this a bug or am I just not seeing the problem here?

[image]

Comment: These are definitely metres as longitude is -180 to +180. I suspect Asc_regrid_grid is in metres, edit your question and show the spatial reference under the source tab in the layer properties window.

Comment: You should have a look to the GenerateTessellation tool if it meets your needs. It is a much simpler/clearer design.

Answer (score 1):

In your Contents Pane you should have a group called *Layers* (if you did not rename this).  If you mouse over, select and highlight,  and then right click Layers you can open the Layer Properties.  Select Coordinate Systems. The default extent values from the Fishnet tool are derived from the units-of-measure from the current coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this something that has changed going from ArcGIS Desktop to Pro? The map layers shows me WGS84 as set CRS but the Layer Properties list both WGS84 and Web Mercator. I've been exclusively working with Geographic CRS layers, how come the fishnet picks the Web Mercator units?